# OpenGL Glew and FreeGlut linking error - GLAPI does not name a type

Tags: opengl, linker, codeblocks, freeglut, glew

I'm trying to use Vertex Buffer Objects in OpenGL (in Code::Blocks) but appareantly you need to to do extra steps to actually use these since I kept having "glGenBuffers was not declared in this scope" errors so after some searching I found out that you can use these 'extended' functions by installing the loading library: GLEW, that handles these problems for you.

Here's what I did: I downloaded GLEW Windows binaries. Placed the glew32.dll inside my Windows/System32 folder and added glew32 to my MinGW's lib folder and added the includes to the MinGW's include folder as well. Just to be safe I also manually added the search directories for lib and include in Code::Blocks as well. Also added '-lglew32' in my linker options.

I've included Glew and Glut as follows:

```
#ifndef INCLUDES_H_INCLUDED
#define INCLUDES_H_INCLUDED

/* Main Header file that contains all the HEADER */
#include <windows.h>

//Some Main constants
#define PI 3.14159265

//Standard includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Open GL and GLUT
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

/* Game Headers */
#include "Game.h"
#include "Functions.h"

#endif // INCLUDES_H_INCLUDED
```

As far as I'm concerned everything should work now but when compiling I get the following error:
    
**'GLAPI' does not name a type**

My main function that initialises glut and glew

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    // #1: GLUT window initialization
    glutInit(&argc, args);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(width/2, height/2);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL 3D Programming.");

    //glutFullScreen(); //optional

    // #2: Registering callbacks
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glewInit();


    // #3: GLUT main loop
    game.init(width, height);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Complete listing of build options in Code::Blocks

```
-lglu32
-lfreeglut
-lglew32
-lwinmm -lgdi32
-lmingw32 -lopengl32
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

I'm completely stuck right now and OpenGL is making it quite hard for me to start learning OpenGL using Vertex Buffers at the moment. Is there something I've done wrong that I'm missing?

---

**UPDATE**
Oké, I got something working at the moment. I added all the includes and libraries to the Code::Blocks/mingw folder as well (instead of 'only' the C:/MinGW folder) and lost my GLAPI error.

I'm not sure if it is a failproof build at the moment since I'm not quite sure about all the steps I've used but for now it seems like it's working.

Comment: Could you try to include windows.h before any other header file? that is, `#include <windows.h>`, if you have not yet done so.

Comment: Haven't included windows.h but added #include <windows.h> just now and didn't make any difference. Does GLEW requires a window header file? (isn't Glew cross platform?)

Comment: Show us a minimal example of your code which exhibits the problem. And include the exact errors you get.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any code to show since it's a linking problem. I'll update the post with my complete include file and my main file if it helps.

Comment: `#include <GL/GL.h>` **after** glew

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, sorry :(